# How to get node id in views fields template file?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to access the nodeid of a row (node) in a view but accessed from the fields template file, however without any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the nid being pulled into the view in the fields section of the view? It should be in the $row variable. Have you tried using xdebug and something like codebug? Setting breakpoints is great for seeing what variables you have access to inside a template.

Comment: You may wish to delete this question and ask it on drupal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in `preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)` hook.

```
$variables['nid'] = $variables['fields']['nid']->content;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your view, in fields section, you have add the field "Content: Nid" and in your template, you have to put this:

```
print $fields['nid']->content;
```